# I receive the email notificaction instantly(VTiger doesn't wait for the date to arrive to send it)

Tags: vtiger

When I create a **ToDo**(or an **event**), and activate the "**Send Notification**" box, and set a future date for it to begin(for example in two days), I receive the email notification instantly(**VTiger** doesn't wait for the date to arrive to send it).

I've tried to find answers by myself and online, but I haven't been able to solve it. `Mi cron` is working OK, and I have my correct timezone configured in `config.inc.php`.

I'm using **Vtiger CRM 6.2.0.**

Do you have any idea of why this is happening, or what can I do to find out or solve it?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It seems that this is the correct way in which VTiger works. Send notification tells the user that a ToDo was created and assigned to him.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is the correct way in which VTiger works. Send notification tells the user that a ToDo was created and assigned to him.

Im not sure how can I email a user when a task is due.